# Object being deselected and the UV map disappearing in Texture Paint Mode

Tags: texturing, objects

When I select all of my object in edit mode, and then go to texture paint mode, my object deselects and turn purple, and the UV map disappears. I've tried many methods to solve this problem but they didn't fully work, such as: Adding a new base color in order to add a texture to the UV map, but only some part of the head could be colored. I've also tried to redo the process, only for it to not work fully and properly.
I will link a video and image of the problem more clearly.

The link to the video: https://youtu.be/bnNjaxyCPIU

The link of the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQLNG.png

Comment: hello, how does your material look like? If you haven't created an image and plugged it into the Principlded BSDF (or Diffuse), it won't give anything (it will give this pink color)

Comment: I've used this link on how to texture paint, and not inserting an image. (Link is attached here)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnRQhH3fEDY&ab_channel=SurfacedStudio

Comment: Also moonbots, what do you mean by inserting an image to the Principled BSDF? Im trying to texture paint and color the object with my cursor. I might be wrong about the previous statement.

Comment: If your statement is right, then help me on what to do in order to get rid of the pink color.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Also use the body of the post to write the actual question, while the title should only summarize it

Comment: I will explain more of it in the description then.

Comment: @Cringe Worth in the Shader Editor you need to plug an Texture > Image Texture node into the Principled BSDF (or Diffuse) node, and you need to have an image loaded in this Image Texture, if it's not the case, click on the New button of the Image Texture in order to create a new image. You need to project an image on the surface of your object if you want to paint on it. If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ok, ill try that method.

Comment: @moonboots, can you help me on that part?

Comment: what part, have you tried what I said? Does it work?

Comment: I'm confused, but I'll give a screenshot link of the Shader editor so you can show me what to do. https://ibb.co/F09Jgfz

Comment: Now you can guide me on what to do

Comment: please share your file (copy paste the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: so would that mean that you can get in my project and help me?

Comment: Would I be able to see the changes you've made if that is true?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c8c73e15f3754ddf9cf0307b767c5c62

Comment: @moonbots, I'll show a video of what happened after your method

Comment: Btw I colored most of the object white and it showed that on the UV map.

Comment: Video link: https://youtu.be/1uztT2NYwmU

Answer (score 0):

See the material you're using for the surface of your skull, it is called *Union2Mtl* and it has no *Image Texture*, you need to create an *Image Texture* and click on its *New* button (or select an already created image):

[image]

Also you need to make sure that the unwrap is correct (*Smart UV Project* will work fine for a 3D view painting) but it seems to be the case here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128179/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-object-being-deselected-and-the-uv-map-disappe).